# can't remove google chrome's default search engine

Tags: google-chrome, search-engine

when i was installed a driver i have installed a spam and thats changed my chrome settings then i have removed the spam app and searched my folders and cleaned the app but unfortunately i could not remove the default search engine 
even after reset the chrome settings and re-installed. please help me how to remove that Default search engine [image]

the thrible dot button is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happened because the chrome says when i try to change my default search engine  “This setting is enforced by your administrator” policy under a search engine in Google Chrome, then my computer is infected with a browser hijacker.

here is the solution:
[Remove “This setting is enforced by your administrator” from Chrome](https://malwaretips.com/blogs/remove-this-setting-is-enforced-by-your-administrator-virus/)